# How to show location of errors, references to members and todos in scrollbar of visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have come over from eclipse (for language reasons) and miss being able to see where errors, members and todos are located in a source file like the red, beige, blue icons respectively in Eclipse.

Is there any way that this can be enabled/ or any plugin that can be installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the Enhanced Scrollbar in the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef).

Comment: Note to new visitors: Productivity Power Tools is not available for Visual Studio 2012, and there does not seem to be any other similar tool available.  Does anyone know of one?

Comment: @MosheKatz PPT for VS2012 was just released: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/11/07/productivity-power-tools-2012.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Errors: View->Error List

Todos: View->Task List

These will show up as tabs in the IDE... you can double-click on an item to be taken to its location in source.