# showing line errors in visual studio

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio

Is there any chance I can see in scrollbar in which line I have errors using visual studio?

Eclipse does it and it is really comfortable. Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443823/how-to-show-location-of-errors-references-to-members-and-todos-in-scrollbar-of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

[image]

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do that.

Comment: @FrioneL I think you mean, "Good answer, thanks.  Any idea if there's a free tool that does this too?"